# reduced code with replace in java

Tags: java, replace

I have input `abc , cde , k " ght`
And I want have output `abc cde k ght`

and here is my code `x = x.replace(" , "," ");
                x = x.replace("+"," ");
                x = x.replace(" _ "," ");
                x = x.replace(" - "," ");
                x = x.replace(" “ "," ");
                x = x.replace(" ” "," ");
                x = x.replace(" ( "," ");
                x = x.replace(" ) "," ");
                x = x.replace(" \" "," ");
                                x.trim();
                                x = x.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");`
my code run right but I think it very bad. someone can tell me improve this code better
thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you're looking to do is to remove all non-letter characters and replace with a collapsed space, this would work better:

```
x = x.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]+", " ");
```

(if you're looking to only remove the specific characters in your original question, it would more like: 
`x = x.replaceAll("[,+_\\-“”()\" ]+", " ");`
)